# Using Taxonomy Terms as slideshow pager (or at least group slideshow pages)

Tags: views

Something I can't seem to figure. How do I use Taxonomy terms as a pager in a slideshow. Essentially slides will be grouped by term. Filters are "destructive" so if I have three terms,  A, B & C clicking A only shows me A. I can't go from 
A->B->C using the next arrow on the slides or vice versa (the needed functionality). If I use the field with the term I get a "page" for for each slide. I need just one for each group (same term) of slides. Any ideas on how to do this.
[image: image with terms and slides]